how to add rotation icon to my transformer rotate anchor in react konva js
How can I add a rotation icon to my rotate anchor in React Konva? I want to customize the appearance of the rotation control to include a specific icon instead of the default handle. Are there any methods, customizations, or examples available for implementing a custom rotation anchor with an icon in React Konva?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
